# Should std::fstream object be defined as class member

Tags: c++, oop, fstream

Should fstream be defined as class member or rather to define it in every function?
I know both works, but what is better way? I'm going to implement functions to read, write, modify, delete this single file.

My goal is to write clean, portable code.

First example to show std::fstream as class member:

```
#include <fstream>

class File {
public:
    bool File::write(const std::string & str) {
        fileStream.open(name, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app | std::fstream::binary);
        bool openSuccess = fileStream.is_open();
        if(openSuccess ){
            fileStream << str;
            closeFile();
        }
        return openSuccess;
    }
//  bool read();
private:
    std::fstream fileStream;
}
```

If code from first example is correct, maybe I should define separate std::ifstream, std::ofstream.

Another example to show std::fstream defined in function:

```
class File {
public:
    bool File::write(const std::string & str) {
        std::fstream fileStream(name, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app | std::fstream::binary);
        bool openSuccess = fileStream.is_open();
        if(openSuccess ){
            fileStream << str;
            closeFile();
        }
        return openSuccess;
    }
//  bool read();
}
```

Second approach is probably safer to use because every time function exits, stream object gets destroyed. But I'm afraid that multiple calls with object construction every time will create huge overlay. Again speed is not my priority but still it's C++, so I don't want to sacrifice efficiency too much.

Comment: There is a fundamentally big difference between the two approaches, and they cannot exactly be substituted for one another in every case. Only you can answer this question for yourself, and for your application. You do that by understanding the inherent differences between the two approaches, and what they mean for your application and program. Noone else can make that decision for you.

Comment: Don't worry about speed until you have to! Regardless, I would personally just use the fstreams without wrapping them in another layer of abstraction

Comment: I understand Sam, but I don't know what to take into account when choosing. In my program both approaches will work correctly, but being so different from each other, I would like to choose wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the class member as a `state` of the object.

In your example, `fileStream` does nothing between invocation of `File::write()`, so it doesn't hold a `state`.

If you would have multiple class methods that write (or read) to the same `fileStream`, it would make sense to have it as a member variable and provide `open` and `close` methods separately from `write`.

Comment: I posted code on this way for simplicity. Real class which we are talking about contains read, delete, and modify methods. If I declare fileStream as member, two following questions arise. Should I declare two separate objects (one for read, one for write)? Should open/ close methods be private?

Comment: @Curious - I would never have two `std::fstream` object sharing one file, it's a recipe for disaster. You may not need `open`/`close` methods at all: you can open a file in a constructor and close it in destructor, if that fits your overall design.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the possibilities of using `std::fstream` are too wide.

- You can use it as a RAII object by opening a file in the constructor and rely on the destructor for closing it. If you go with this approach, you should match the lifetime of the object accordingly. For instance, if you have a method for opening, modifying, and closing a file, then use `std::fstream` as a local object. If you need a file to be kept open during some object's entire lifetime, then use `std::fstream` as its class field.
- Also, you can open/close/reopen files with `open` and `close` methods of `std::fstream`. It makes things more complicated. A `std::fstream` object can be reused for working with one or more files. For instance, by having one global `std::fstream` object, you can process multiple files consequently.